# Want to plot rectangles given their width,height and the cartesian origin (0,0)

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry

[image: what the floorplan should look like]

[image]

[image]

**The info I am given** : block_ID, block_width, block_height as well as how the cuts between the rectangles are(horizontal or vertical); for example two rectangles can be joined by a horizontal cut or a vertical cut. **See above picture for greater clarity**(H symbolizes horizontal cut and likewise V for vertical cuts). The order of cuts on the blocks can be represented as a normalized polish expression or a skewed binary tree.

**What i tried till now** : I tried using a stack based approach where I would push the digits in the polish expression into a stack and would pop the top 2 elements from the stack when I came across a character(H OR V) and then join these 2 blocks (take max of height and add the widths for vertical cuts and vice versa for horizontal) and push this new 'edited' block into the stack again.

**Code for the same :**

```
def plot_floorplan_area(blocks, polish_expression,num_blocks):
# Initialize the plot
curmax=num_blocks
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, xmax+5) 
ax.set_ylim(0,ymax+5) 
ax.set_xlabel('Width')
ax.set_ylabel('Height')
ax.set_title('Floorplan')
x, y = 0, 0
stack=[]
for c in polish_expression:
  if c.isdigit():
    stack.append(int(c))
    c=int(c)
    c-=1
    curwid=blocks[c][1]
    curht=blocks[c][2]
    left_bottom=(x,y)
    rect = Rectangle(left_bottom, curwid, curht, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
    center_x = left_bottom[0] + curwid / 2
    center_y = left_bottom[1] + curht / 2
    ax.text(center_x, center_y, str(blocks[c][0]), ha='center', va='center', fontsize=12)
    ax.add_patch(rect)
  elif c=='H':#horizontal cut.
    el1=stack.pop()
    el2=stack.pop()
    el1-=1
    el2-=1
    curwid=max(blocks[el1][1],blocks[el2][1])
    curht=blocks[el2][2]+blocks[el1][2]
    rect = Rectangle(left_bottom, curwid, curht, linewidth=0, edgecolor='none', facecolor='none', alpha=0)
    x+=curwid
    y+=curht
    curmax+=1
    stack.append(curmax)
  elif c=='V':
    el1=stack.pop()
    el2=stack.pop()
    el1-=1
    el2-=1
    curht=max(blocks[el1][2],blocks[el2][2])
    curwid=blocks[el2][1]+blocks[el1][1]
    rect = Rectangle(left_bottom, curwid, curht, linewidth=0, edgecolor='none', facecolor='none', alpha=0)
    x+=curwid
    y+=curht
    curmax+=1
    stack.append(curmax)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()``
```

**Structure of a row of the blocks matrix : {ID,width,height,area} .**

Could anyone tell me alternate approaches/corrections to the existing approach as this one is yielding wrong outputs.

EDIT: I have also addded what the floorplan plot should look like

**The polish expression is basically the postorder traversal of the tree above.**

Comment: I have no idea what are you asking about...

Comment: Let me explain again in brief: I am given a Polish Expression for a  VLSI floorplan (consists of blocks which are represented by numbers and V or H joins to join 2 blocks) I want to plot a floorplan(arrangement of the blocks which are fixed size rectangles). I have an idea of how to using a stack but the exact implementation is going all wrong.

Comment: Example of a polish expression :  1 2 V 3 H 4 5 6 V H 7 V H